# Searching for a string in multiple files on Linux

Tags: linux, search, grep

How to search in multiple files or folders for a string inside a plain text file?

For example I need to find the string "foo" in all files in the folder "/home/thisuser/bar/baz/"

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to have read privileges on the files you will be searching in. If you do have them, then simply use

```
grep -r "foo" /home/thisuser/bar/baz/*
```

to search in a certain folder or

```
grep "foo" /home/thisuser/bar/baz/somefile.txt
```

if you need to search in a specific file, in this case "somefile.txt".
Basically the syntax is

```
grep [options] [searched string] [path]
// -r is an option which states that it will use recursive search
```

Another useful options are "-n" to show on which line in which file the string is located, "-i" to ignore case, "-s" to suppress some messages like "can't read file" or "not found" and "-I" to ignore binary files.

If you use

```
grep -rnisI "foo" /home/thisuser/bar/baz/*
```

you will exactly know where to look.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
grep -r "foo" /home/thisuser/bar/baz/
```

Comment: Did you even read the answer which I provided directly to this question?